# Abelian Groups of order 2000

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Classify, up to isomorphism, all abelian groups of order 2,000, giving the
standard form of each group in your list. (The standard form is also called
the invariant factor decomposition.)

Comment: Eer....where in your question do characters appear??

Comment: sorry, I changed the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$2,000=2^4\cdot 5^3$$

Now, the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $\,4\,$ is $\,5\,$, and the number of partitions of $\,3\,$ is $\,3\,$ , so the number of different abelian groups of order $\,2,000\,$ up to isomorphism is $\,5\cdot 3=15\,$ .

Some of them are:

$$C_{2,000}\;,\;C_{16}\times C_{25}\times C_5\;,\;C_8\times C_2\times C_5\times C_5\ \times C_5\;,\;etc.$$

Comment: Can I use Zn instead of Cn?

Comment: I think so, but this can be a nuisance as the group operation changes to addition. But if you're more used to this no problem.